# Django: Serving SVGs

Tags: django, svg, amazon-s3, django-staticfiles

In my Django project, I have a JS library that also uses SVGs for icons. These files are in an S3 bucket - meaning not on my own domain. When the JS is initiated, it tries to load the SVG icons and that throws a browser error in Chrome:

```
Unsafe attempt to load URL https://s3.amazonaws.com/<mydomain.com>/static/pixie/assets/icons/merged.svg
from frame with URL 
<mydomain.com>/images/pixie/dcfcf90e-d4fa-4bde-bb6b-6cebe00e6d7a/. 
Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Is there a way to serve these SVGs from my project directly?

If the SVGs are served from my own domain, ex. `<mydomain.com>/svgs/merged.svg`, then I think the "unsafe attempt to load" error would be resolved.

Specifically, within the .js file

```
return t.prototype.ngOnInit = function() {
                        this.path = this.settings.getAssetUrl("icons/merged.svg") + "#" + this.name, this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, ("icon-" + this.name).replace(/ /g, "-"))
                    }, t
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. Point a URL at a view:

```
def svgview(request):
    file = open('/app/<app_name>/static/pixie/assets/icons/merged.svg', 'rb')
    response = HttpResponse(content=file)
    response['Content-Type'] = 'image/svg+xml'
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there doesn't look to be a way around this issue on the framework/CORS level. The only way to load an external SVG from a CDN is via a rather unseemly Ajax call.

It's nothing you've done wrong - more a fundamental problem: the `<use>` tag's `xlink:href` will ***NEVER*** load content from a remote server, even with Cross-Origin Resource Sharing turned on.

To load the SVG via an XMLHttpRequest you'll need to do something like the following:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("GET", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/<mydomain.com>/static/pixie/assets/icons/merged.svg", true);
ajax.send();
ajax.onload = function(e) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
  document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.childNodes[0]);
}
```

But, is this all worth it? Considering your SVG must be fairly lightweight I assume?

Comment: Re external SVG- I think I'm trying to load it from Django directly so that it isn't an external SVG. I have the files currently in my /static/ directory. When collect static is run, then those files are loaded into the static directory I'm using in S3. Ultimately it may be an issue where there isn't a way to serve those locally. I'll tinker with loading it via XMLHttpRequest. It may be to load them that way, and then change the fie to reference those objects.

Comment: @Emile You should be able to serve any local assets locally, it seems to me that your assets are being moved onto your CDN and then the only asset which is causing this issue is your SVG. Are you loading any other assets (.css, .js etc) via this AWS3 CDN?

Comment: @Michael I am currently serving all of my static assets from S3. Rather than serving them all locally, I'm trying to load only this library locally. That would allow me to keep my STATIC settings as is for serving the remaining files from S3. By loading the library locally, get around the CORS issue and loading external URL error.

Comment: So other files (such as css, js etc) are all loading without the above issue?

Comment: Correct, I just added the line in question within the .js file. Because it is calling for the icons, it is doing so from s3. If I can just point a URL to the .svg file within Django, then I could hard code it to look at a safe file behind my domain. Or just serve the whole library locally vs change that line.

Comment: AAAhhhhhh yes - try my above amending solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178799/discussion-between-emile-and-micheal-j-roberts).